# Check box not checked according to the stored array of id

Tags: javascript, combobox, kendo-ui

```js
var data;
var gridColumns;
var grid;
var showlist;
var viewModel;

viewModel = kendo.observable({
  showlist:false,

});

kendo.bind($(checklist), viewModel);

function onChange() {
    viewModel = kendo.observable({
      showlist:true, 
    });
filterinfo(cType.value());
kendo.bind($(checklist), viewModel);
  }

function filterinfo(value)
{
  var treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
  if(treeView){
    treeView.destroy();
    $("#treeview").html("");
  }

  switch(value){
    case "1":
      treeView = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
          checkboxes   : {
            checkChildren: false,
            template     : $("#template").html()
          },
          dataSource   : PrimaryProbe,
          dataTextField: "value"
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
      
      function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
    //console.log(nodes);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].checked) {
            checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
        }
        if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
            checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
        }
    }
}

// show checked node IDs on datasource change
treeView.dataSource.bind("change", function () {
    var message;
    var checkedNodes = [];

    checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
    if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {
        message = "IDs of checked nodes: " + checkedNodes.join(",");
    } else {
        message = "No nodes checked.";
    }
    $("#result").html(message);
});
      
      
      
      break;
    case "2":
      treeView = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
          checkboxes   : {
            checkChildren: false,
            template     : $("#template").html()
          },
          dataSource   : Probe,
          dataTextField: "value"
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
      
      function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
    //console.log(nodes);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].checked) {
            checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
        }
        if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
            checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
        }
    }
}

// show checked node IDs on datasource change
treeView.dataSource.bind("change", function () {
    var message;
    var checkedNodes = [];

    checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
    if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {
        message = "IDs of checked nodes: " + checkedNodes.join(",");
    } else {
        message = "No nodes checked.";
    }
    $("#result").html(message);
});
      break;
  }
}

var clientType = [{"clientTypeID":1,"clientTypeName":"PrimaryProbe"},
                  {"clientTypeID":2,"clientTypeName":"Probe"}]


var cType = $("#clientType").kendoComboBox({
                        filter: "contains",
                        change: onChange,
                        placeholder: "Filter by client type",
                        dataTextField: "clientTypeName",
                        dataValueField: "clientTypeID",
                        dataSource: {
                            data:clientType
                        }
                    }).data("kendoComboBox");




var Probe = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  data: [
    { id      : 1,
     parent_id: 0,
     value    : "General Information - Probe",
     expanded : true,
     items    : [
       { id: 11, parent_id: 1, value: "CPU Model"},
       { id: 12, parent_id: 1, value: "CPU Usage" },
       { id: 13, parent_id: 1, value: "Free Space"},
       { id: 14, parent_id: 1, value: "Hardware Model"},
       { id: 15, parent_id: 1, value: "Master/Slave Mode"},
       { id: 16, parent_id: 1, value: "Memory Usage" },
       { id: 17, parent_id: 1, value: "Product Version" },
       { id: 18, parent_id: 1, value: "Software Version" }
     ]},
    { id      : 2,
     parent_id: 0,
     value    : "Sim Pool Information - Probe",
     expanded : true,
     items    : [
       { id: 21, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 1"},
       { id: 22, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 2"},
       { id: 23, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 3"},
       { id: 24, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 4"},
       { id: 25, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 5"},
       { id: 26, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 6"},
       { id: 27, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 7"},
       { id: 28, parent_id: 2, value: "Slot 8"}
     ]},
    {
      id       : 3,
      parent_id: 0,
      value    : "Trace Files Information - Probe",
      expanded : true,
      items    : [
        { id: 31,parent_id: 3, value: "FTP Upload Status"},
        { id: 32,parent_id: 3, value: "Remaining Agent Trace Files" },
        { id: 33,parent_id: 3, value: "Remaining Probe Trace Files" },
        { id: 34,parent_id: 3, value: "Remaining TRP Log Files"}
      ]
    }
  ]
});
var PrimaryProbe = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  data: [
    { id      : 5,
     parent_id: 0,
     value    : "General - Primary Probe",
     expanded : true,
     items    : [
       { id: 51, parent_id: 5, value: "Agent Running Mode"},
       { id: 52, parent_id: 5, value: "Agent Version"},
       { id: 53, parent_id: 5, value: "Master/Slave Mode"},
       { id: 54, parent_id: 5, value: "Manufacturer"},
       { id: 55, parent_id: 5, value: "Model"},
       { id: 56, parent_id: 5, value: "Software Version"}
     ]}
  ]
});





// function that gathers IDs of checked nodes


function add(){  
  viewModel = kendo.observable({
  showlist:true,

});
kendo.bind($(checklist), viewModel);

  
}
function check(){ 

}
```

```css
#fieldlist {
                   margin: 0;
                   padding: 0;
               }
       
               #fieldlist li {
                   list-style: none;
                   padding-bottom: 1.5em;
                   text-align: left;
               }
       
               #fieldlist label {
                   display: block;
                   padding-bottom: .3em;
                   font-weight: bold;
                   text-transform: uppercase;
                   font-size: 12px;
               }

.searchClientText {
    width: 222px !important;
    height: 25px !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.checkboxList {
  margin: 0 0 -1em;
  padding: 0;
}

.checkboxList li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

td {
  width:150px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="demo-section k-content">
    
    <ul id="fieldlist">
      <li>
        <input id="clientType" style="width:auto" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <script id="template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    # if(!item.hasChildren){ #
    <input type='hidden' id='#= item.id #' parent_id='#= item.parent_id #' d_text='#= item.value #'/>
    <input type='checkbox' id_a='#= item.id #' name='c_#= item.id #' value='true'/>
    #}else{#
    <div id='#= item.id #' style='display:none;' parent_id='#= item.parent_id #' d_text='#= item.value #'/>
    #}#
</script>
  <div id="checklist" data-bind="visible: showlist">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><div id="treeview"></div><div id="result"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>



  

</body>
</html>
```

There will be a combo box with ["Primary Probe","Probe"] and once i select an option from the combo box will be showing a list of check box and once the check box is checked then it will get the id and display in the result.

The problem:
The problem is when i change the option from primary probe to probe or probe to primary probe of the combo box it will uncheck my selected combo box.

How to make the system load my checked id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new TreeView instances that are created in `filterinfo`, do not have a `change` handler attached to their dataSources. This is currently done only once for the first TreeView instance, that's why the checked IDs are displayed only for this instance.

Comment: I had try many time on adding the change handler but it seem not working. Help me check and modify if needed on the jsbin link below
[link](http://jsbin.com/gupamomodi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: In the provided example, `treeView.dataSource.bind("change", ...)` is only executed for **case 2** in the `filterinfo()` function `switch`. Make it execute for both cases.

Comment: [sample code](http://jsbin.com/yuyaciz/edit?js,output) The problem now is whenever i change the combo box option then my checked checkbox will be clear but the message it will said i check the previous selection. How to make the checkbox checked according to the previous id